Two sigma-algebras on $l^\infty$
Let $\mathcal{B}_w(l^\infty)$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the weak topology on $l^\infty$. Let $Cyl(l^\infty)$ denote the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra, that is, it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all linear continuous functionals on $l^\infty$. We want to prove that the inclusion $Cyl(l^\infty)\subset \mathcal{B}_w(l^\infty)$ is strict.
Fremlin writes in [1] that this inclusion is indeed strict. Book [2] also states that these sigma-algebras are different. In both cases, the authors refer to Talagrand's article [3]. But in this work there is no such result. Please help me understand why this is true. Thanks.
[1] D.H. Fremlin. Borel sets in non-separable Banach spaces
[2] Vakhania, N. N.; Tarieladze, V. I.; Chobanyan, S. A. (1987). Probability Distributions on Banach Spaces
[3] M.Talagrand. Comparaison des boreliens d’un espace de Banach pour les
topologies fortes et faibles

I think this might help you:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4176643/is-the-sigma-algebra-generated-by-weak-topology-of-non-separable-banach-spa

This is a very interesting question. Indeed, all references seem to point to Talagrand's paper (which I can not read since I do not know French and can not translate since the paper I have available is in image format.) Let me point out that the easier inclusion $Cyl (\ell_\infty) \subsetneq B(\ell_\infty)$ is presented in [2] Proposition 2.9. The author defines a map $\xi \colon [0,1] \to \ell_\infty$ that is $Cyl$-measurable but not borel-measurable.

(Cont...) The latter uses the fact that for $A\subset [0,1]$ non-measurable, since $ξ$ is injective, $\xi^{-1}(\xi(A)) = A$ is non-measurable and $\xi(A)$ is closed. Unfortunately, $\xi(A)$ is not weakly-closed (as far as I can tell) and so the proof does not give that $\xi$ is not $B_w(\ell_\infty)$-measurable.

@Ramiro, I've already seen this post. Unfortunately, there is no answer there.

The results of [MaPl] answer our question (see Proposition 5.2 and the diagram before it). However, the question remains: why do the authors of [1] and [2] refer to Talagrand's work? It may also be that they are referring to the result that Borel $\sigma$-algebras are distinct, and our question is obvious to them. [MaPl] Witold Marciszewski, Grzegorz Plebanek. On Borel structures in the Banach space $C(\beta\omega)$, 2013.

Often we merely quote results in papers.  We include proofs only if (a) our proof is better than the existing one or (b) this is an expository account (collecting existing results rather than producing new ones).
